# Print specific columns from an excel file imported to python

Tags: python

I have a table as below:

[image: Mapping]

How can I print all the sources that have an `'X'` for a particular column?. For example, if I want to specify `"Make"`, the `output` should be:

```
Delivery
Reputation
Profitability
```

**PS:** The idea is to import the excel file in `python` and do this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "yourexcelfile"
dataframe = pd.read_excel(filename)
frame  = dataframe.loc[dataframe["make"] == "X"]
print(frame["source"])
```